# Android Studio 3.1.4 gridlayout v7:28 not rendering

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB3Q7.jpg)I'm trying to work with the GridLayout, but I'm having this issue that when I put an image inside the grid, it only shows a small dot inside the grid, tried expanding it with the mouse but doesn't work, also tried adjusting the image layout width and height to 150dp and still seeing the same spot... tried to run it on my device but failed error: not well-formed (invalid token) with this message:

```
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: not well-formed (invalid token)., sources=[C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\SouthparkCharactersGrid\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:25], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

The image works well outside of the grid, and it happens the same with any other default image of android, buttons as well... what might be happening?

these are my XML codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="274dp"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="205dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kyle" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post all relevant XML files and your code?

Comment: what does `activity_main.xml` say at line `line 25` ??

Comment: there, I have posted the XML

Answer (score 1):

solved replaced "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" by "GridLayout" on top and bottom and that made it work

Comment: As what? We must know!

Comment: He replaced "<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" to "<GridLayout"